# How many size of background images should I create for different devices in Android?

Tags: android

Here, I have a 320X480 images(photos) and wants to put it as my background image in an application.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">    

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, when I put it in different devices, the image will become very strange (I don't know whether it is strange because it re-size the image or not).
So, how to solve this problems??
Because there is a photo and in photo there is one person. It will make very strange if the person looks very thin in device A but very fat in device B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to create a background for the full screen. The 3 solutions I'd recommend is following:

One Image as background solution is the one most often used for this to work you'll have to make one for each major screen size = ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi and make it:

1. centered in the layout with a solid background color that blends with the centered image or
2. make it a 9-patch image that will stretch in a proper way.
3. The third solution is to create a tiled layout where you use one image and then copy it all over the screen in a tilled fashion.
4. A thing that might work in some cases is to have 1 image and then cut it out depending on the screen size. This might work but it will give out of memory exception on small/old phones if the image is too large, so again have 1 image for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi.

Example for (1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@drawable/splash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The splash image could have any size, the important thing is that the outer parts of the image blends into the background color, this could be done by having an image with a background color that slowly blends into the same color as the background.

An example for (4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        >
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```